# Multi-dimensional char array and pointer assignment

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

Say I have a 3-dimensional char array

```
char strList[CONST_A][CONST_B][CONST_C];
```

And an array pointer (changed after comments pointed out the error):

```
char * args[CONST_C];
```

I want to pick a part of `strList` and make `args` to be that value. For example, if `strList` representing something like

```
{{"Your", "question", "is", "ready", "to", "publish!"},
 {"Our", "automated", "system", "checked", "for", "ways", "to", "improve", "your", "question"},
 {"and", "found", "none."}}
```

and I want args to be

```
{"and", "found", "none."}
```

how should I do it?

I've tried to use `args = strlist[someIndex];` but got an error saying `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[100]’ from type ‘char (*)[100]’` , `strcpy` also seems to fail (probably due to `args` was not allocated with enough space?), what should I do to properly assign `args`?

edit: `args` has been used prior to the assignment, so changing the type of `args`, while plausible, does require a lot of extra work on other parts of the code.

Comment: `char * args[CONST_C];` this is not a pointer to array, this is an array of pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is an array of pointers, a better option would be a pointer to array:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s1nzx6h8q)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONST_A 5
#define CONST_B 10
#define CONST_C 15

int main(void) {
  char strList[CONST_A][CONST_B][CONST_C] = {
      {"Your", "question", "is", "ready", "to", "publish!"},
      {"Our", "automated", "system", "checked", "for", "ways", "to", "improve",
       "your", "question"},
      {"and", "found", "none."}};

  char(*args)[CONST_C] = strList[2];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s ", args[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
and found none.
```

---

If you want to use your original array of pointers, you can also do it, but the assignments would also have to be *manual* sort of speak, you would need to iterate over the arrays to make the assigments, something like:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9rK5s6fKG)

```
char *args[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    args[i] = strList[2][i];
}
```

---

Like you asked in the comments, you can have a single `char` pointer pointing to one of the strings, like for instance:

```
char *args = strList[2][0]; // and
args = strList[2][1];       // found
...
```

But iterating over the pointer like in the first example is not possible, the dimension of the array is necessary for a correct iteration, hence the need for a pointer to array.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the type of  `ptr`? In my case, the `ptr` was declared as `char * prt` and a lot of code has been using this, changing it to `char (*ptr)` would require extra works on the rest of the code. Thank you.

Comment: @AmarthGûl, it's perfectly possible, `char *ptr = strList[2][0];` will point to `and`, `ptr = strList[2][1]` will point to `found`, etc, but to iterate in a for loop like I have in my code, using the pointer, a pointer to array is needed.

Comment: @AmarthGûl You can always use the original array of pointers solution, is not as natural as the first, but it 's certainly better than a char pointer. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pointer to an array:

```
char (*args)[CONST_C] = strList[2];
```

Now code:

```
    puts(args[0]);
    puts(args[1]);
    puts(args[2]);
```

will produce:

```
and
found
none.
```